# stringstream access violation with _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have stumbled across a problem compiling in DEBUG mode in Visual Studio 2015 where I get an access violation error with the following code (it has been fine in release mode or if `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 1` or `2`). The problem has only surfaced since I set `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0` in the project properties (I've added as a `#define` here for simplicity which also causes an error):

```
#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

bool try_parse(const std::string& s, double& v)
{
    std::stringstream stream;

    std::locale invariant_number_locale{ std::locale{ "" }, new std::numpunct<char>() };

    stream.imbue(invariant_number_locale);

    stream << s;

    stream >> v;

    return !stream.fail();
}

int main()
{
    double v;
    std::string s = "123";

    try_parse(s, v);

    std::cout << "d = " << v << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Done...";
    std::getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem seems to the line `stream.imbue(invariant_number_locale);`.

Comment: I' m not sure this is a minimal example yet. Try commenting lines out one by one ( beginning with the stream operations in `try_parse`) and recompiling until it doesn't crash while compiling.

Comment: @Spencer, I have now done that

Comment: The template specializations of std::stringstream are built into msvcp140d.dll, the debug build of the standard C++ library.  It was built with iterator debugging enabled.  Kaboom.  Just never do this, debug with small data sets, test perf only with the Release build.

Comment: @HansPassant does the same apply to Visual Studio 2013? What is the proper way to override `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` in this case?

Comment: @HansPassant if we do not imbue custom locale, there is no problem. How is this related?

Comment: @Mikhail see my answer and a link with feedback from MS in it.

Comment: @HansPassant It does feed into the whole question of why we have to debug STL at the same time we're debugging our own code. Also, I've had all sorts of occasions where a subtle bug wasn't caught until 2 million records in.

Comment: Hmya, it is C++.  Like the old joke goes, if car design evolved the way C++ evolved then you could today buy one that goes 900 mph, get 1200 miles on a gallon of fuel and kill you in less than an hour.  Don't stomp the gas pedal until you know it is safe.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the answer is if you use facets you must use `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2` in debug mode as per this thread:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2655363

Thanks to @HansPassant for pointing me in the right direction.